# DtypeWarning: Columns (13) have mixed types

Tags: python, pandas

When I run the following code with the column specified as `object`, I get the warning

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2785: DtypeWarning: Columns (13) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
```

I also tried setting `low_memory=False`, and using both false low memory and specifying the data type, but the error won't go.

The weirdest thing is that I used the exact code on another 2 files and got no errors.

What can I do?

*Ps. This is the biggest file of all the 3. It has more than 400,000 rows and 14 columns. The others have 200,000 + and 170,000 + rows*

```
re = requests.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/baywheels-data/202002-baywheels-tripdata.csv.zip')
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(re.content))
csvfile = zip_file.open('202002-baywheels-tripdata.csv')

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
df.to_csv('Ford02-2020.csv',index=False)

df2 = pd.read_csv('Ford02-2020.csv', dtype={'rental_access_method': object})
df2.head()
```

### Sample data from column `'rental_access_method'`

```py
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
...
432349    app
432350    app
432351    app
432352    app
432353    app
Name: rental_access_method, dtype: object
```

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. The warning occurs with `df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)`, but not with `df2 = pd.read_csv('Ford02-2020.csv', dtype={'rental_access_method': object})`. Also the warning does not occur with `df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, low_memory=False)`. I'm voting to close this as not reproducible.

Comment: So, why doesn't it appear with the other 2 files although I used the same code, only changing the file numbers?

Comment: No idea, because I don't have the other files. However `NaN` is a `float` type and `app` is a `string` type. So when the dataframe is created, the warning occurs because pandas doesn't know how to deal with a column with more than one data type.

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/baywheels-data/202001-baywheels-tripdata.csv.zip
https://s3.amazonaws.com/baywheels-data/202003-baywheels-tripdata.csv.zip

May be you can look at them if you have some time

Comment: All 3 files have the same mixed data type in the last column, which either has `'app'` or is empty. The empty value is being replaced with `NaN`.